# Nesting settings.gradle

Tags: gradle

Is it possible to nest multiple settings.gradle files for a multi module project?

E.g. settings.gradle of Project A should include settings.gradle of Project A_a

```
A (include ':A_a',':A_b')
A_a (include 'A_a_1','A_a_2','A_a_3')
A_a_1
A_a_2
A_a_3
A_b
```

Comment: I was able to do this in a fairly sane way: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29664571/204480

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there should only be one settings.gradle in the root project of the build. Gradle expects it to be that way, that's how it was built. It will

Please see the [Build Lifecycle](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html) documentation of gradle for a full explanation. Particularly the *Initialization* chapter.

Comment: And why there should only be one settings.gradle? Would it be a bad practice or it is technically not possible?

Comment: Agree w this answer totally, but just adding -  It seems they give you an API if you would like to tinker with the recommended build structure.

I have not used it, but check out the section titled: "56.4. Running tasks by their absolute path" - http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:running_partial_build_from_the_root

Comment: There can be several settings.gradle files in your project, however, Gradle is only taking the rootProject one into account by default. There are different approaches around which realize a load of multiple settings.gradle files. Take a look at the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12154031/multiple-settings-gradle-files-for-multiple-projects-building/)

Answer (score 0):

As of 2023, Gradle (8.x) provides documentation for structuring large projects with several settings.gradle by using an umbrella build.

For example:

```
├── android-app
│   └── settings.gradle
├── server-application
│   └── settings.gradle
│
├── admin-feature
│   └── settings.gradle
├── user-feature
│   └── settings.gradle
```

You can just check it here https://docs.gradle.org/8.0/userguide/structuring_software_products.html or here https://docs.gradle.org/8.0/userguide/structuring_software_products_details.html