# Gradle specify settings dir path for a sub project

Tags: gradle, multi-project

In a multi-project build I have a module that in itself is composed of two sub-projects. If I just want the option of building the top-level module but also ensure both the sub-projects within it are also built, how I do achieve this?

```
include 'moduleA', 'moduleB', 'moduleC' (root project settings.gradle)
project(':moduleC').projectDir = new File('path to custom module that includes sub-projects)
project(':moduleC').settingsDir = ?? (gradle fails because there is no settingsDir path)
```

but moduleC has a settings.gradle in itself that has

```
include 'api'
include 'server'
```

Now I want both these to be triggered when I specify `gradlew :moduleC:build`, but instead it just builds moduleC root project. Is there a way? This use case does seem valid to me (i.e. for modularity, you want to keep the inclusion of sub-projects at moduleC's level and not at root level).

Thanks,
Paddy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Gradle 2.2, only a single `settings.gradle` per build is supported. If that file contains `include "moduleC:api"` and `include "moduleC:server"`, then running `gradle build` from `moduleC`'s project directory will also build `api` and `server`.

Comment: Hi @Peter, what will gradlew :moduleC:build do if I try it from root project directory? Will it still build both api and server or will tha happen only if I run gradle from moduleC's project directory?

Comment: No, it will just run the `build` task in `moduleC` (or error out if there isn't any). Of course, you can always declare your own task that  `dependsOn ":moduleC:api:build"` and `dependsOn ":moduleC:server:build"`.

Comment: Is it like tasks[':moduleC:build'].dependsOn(':moduleC:api:build') for example?

Comment: Depending on your exact motivations/needs, you might do something like `task buildAll { dependsOn build, ":moduleC:api:build", ":moduleC:server:build" }` in `moduleC/build.gradle`.

Comment: Here's a technique I used to get around this limitation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29664571/204480