# Gradle - inherit repositories from a module

Tags: android, maven, gradle, dependencies

First of all, I explain my project setups. I use the words Project/Module as used in Android Studio.

I have a setup of my projects like following:

- LibraryProject => a project that just groups my libraries, that I use in other projects, if necessary

  - BackupLibrary (Module)
  - DatabseLibrary (Module)
  - MainUtilityLibrary (Module)
  - DialogLibrary (Module)
- MyProject1

  - App (Project)
  - DialogLibrary (Module, referenced from DIRFFERENT project)

**My Project1 now looks like following:**

1) I reference the module from the other project, that I want to use (done in `settings.gradle (Project Settings)` file:

```
include ':app'

include ':dialogLibrary '
project(':dialogLibrary ').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../LibraryProject/DialogLibrary ')
```

2) I add the foreign library module as a dependency to my app's `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':dialogLibrary ')
}
```

---

**My LibraryProject looks like following:**

I add the repository and the dependency directly to the module's `build.gradle' (this is enough to build the module on it's own without a problem):

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/drummer-aidan/maven' }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.afollestad:material-dialogs:0.7.5.2'
}
```

---

**Problem**

The setup so far does not work for MyProject1. I have to add `maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/drummer-aidan/maven' }` to MyProject1 as well, the `compile project(':dialogLibrary ')` is not enough. I have to add the dependency that should somehow be inherited from the LibraryModule to MyProject1 Project `build.gradle`again like following:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/drummer-aidan/maven' } // com.afollestad:material-dialogs
    }
}
```

Otherwise, i can't compile my project. This way seems like doing something twice that probably can be done automatically. But how? This way, whenever I include a module from my LibraryProject, I have to check if I need an additional maven repo...

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with the fact that Gradle has no knowledge of the `LibraryProject`'s settings.gradle file while building `MyProject1`. So it includes the `dialogLibrary` as if it is a normal subproject of it's own. This explains the reason why the Maven repo is not know to `MyProject`; `LibraryProject`'s configuration has not been loaded.

Maybe you can include the `dialogLibrary` through the `LibraryProject`? Although I did some testing and could NOT get it to work. It probably has to do with a limitation of Gradle. There is a StackOverflow post about multiple settings.gradle files [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12154031/multiple-settings-gradle-files-for-multiple-projects-building/).

A work around could be to build the Modules of the LibraryProject and use them instead. For example build the DialogLibrary to a jar, upload it to a Maven repository and than in your App project just include DialogLibrary as normal dependency (don't forget to include the Maven repo).