# Having a multi-module project inside of another multi-module project in gradle

Tags: gradle

I have this question with regards to a gradle multi-module setup:

I have

```
root project
   build.gradle 
   settings.gradle <-include 'subproject','multimodule'
   multi module project
       build.gradle
       settings.gradle <- include multi1, multi2
       multi1
           build.gradle
       multi2
           build.gradle <- compile project(':multi1')
   subproject
       build.gradle <- How can this reference multi1?
       settings.gradle
```

Now both subproject and multi2 needs to refer to multi1. multi2 is easily able to refer to multi1. But how do I make subproject refer multi1?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9013597/gradle-multi-module-project-setup?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it is a limitation of Gradle that it does not support multiple root/sub-projects. This is because Gradle does not support the use of multiple settings.gradle files in a project setup. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12154031/multiple-settings-gradle-files-for-multiple-projects-building/) question. And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30797518/gradle-inherit-repositories-from-a-module/30810945#30810945) answer from me on a related question.